# El toUpperCase() como se usa

Tags: javascript, html

El `toUpperCase()`, me gustaría que me digan como se utiliza y que me den ejemplos ya que me es difícil entender su estructura.

Comment: Hola @Laura, deberías darte una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como funciona el sitio. :D

Comment: es cuestión de agregar al final de una cadena `.ToUpperCase` , no tiene complicidad, para qué caso en específico lo necesitas?

Comment: [console.log( "aaaaabbbbbbbcccccc".toUpperCase() );](http://jsbin.com/saqetokamu/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: Solo poniendo toUpperCase() en google te salen cientos de ejemplos...

Comment: **Solo convierte una cadena a Mayúsculas.**  Me sorprende ver que piden aclaración de la pregunta o que añada lo que ha intentado y al final terminan respondiendo lo cuál se contradicen. [ver enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toUpperCase) además hay más métodos como convertir a minúsculas. _lower_.

Comment: [Aquí tienes la respuesta a tu pregunta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toUpperCase). Fuente oficial y en el idioma de Cervantes. Hay ejemplos y todo. Su estructura no es tan difícil, funciona como una llamada a cualquier método.

Answer (score 6):

`String#toUpperCase()` convierte la cadena de string a mayuscula:

```js
var nombre = "einer";
console.log(nombre.toUpperCase());
```

Los tipo de datos como Integer, Boolean, Date, y Float y no tienen el metodo `toUpperCase()`, por lo que te lanzara un error al momento de llamar el metodo. Por ejemplo:

```js
var numero = 888;
console.log(numero.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

Es muy sencillo:

```
var cadena = "hola";

alert(cadena.toUpperCase())
```

Solo usas el método en la variable donde tienes el texto que deseas aplicar.

Fuente: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

Comment: Te sugeriría para futuras respuestas que uses como referencia MDN, además hay bastante información en español: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toUpperCase

Comment: Lo tomare en cuenta, gracias.

Comment: "totoUpperCase()"... =0 un typo!

Answer (score 0):

El método [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toUpperCase) convierte de una cadena string todos los caracteres en mayúsculas. Unicamente aplica para tipos de dato String.

Como ejemplo si defines una cadena:

```
var cadena = "Laura en StackOverflow!";
```

y aplicas el método [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toUpperCase),

```
var resultado = cadena.toUpperCase();
```

obtienes como resultado la misma cadena pero  con todos los caracteres en mayúsculas:

```
LAURA EN STACKOVERFLOW!.
```

---

ejemplo:

```js
function convierteMayusculas() {
    var cadena = "Laura en StackOverflow!.";
    var resultado = cadena.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = resultado ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Convierte el texto a mayusculas:</h1>
<p>Laura en StackOverflow!.</p>

<button onclick="convierteMayusculas()">Convertir</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```